# Calling shell command in Matlab

Tags: windows, shell, matlab, environment-variables

I recently installed a software package called GPSToolkit on my Windows machine. The bin directory was automatically added to my PATH and I can execute the GPS functions from any directory. However, when I attempt to make a system call within Matlab none of the functions in the GPS toolkit can be found. The specific error message reads "'rinexpvt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Does Matlab have a different set of environmental variables? Maybe the operating system considers Matlab to be a different "User"? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance --Dom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can specify the fully qualified path in your system call
- You can check and modify the system path with getenv() and setenv()

check http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setenv.html for examples

```
setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') '; C:\the\path\to\your\tool']);
```

Comment: I tried adding the path using setenv but i still get the same error message :/ Thanks for the response!

Comment: Try calling system() with the full path as part of the command string to satisfy yourself that it is a path problem.

Comment: Ya that works for now. Maybe I'll include the GPS toolkit functions in my own bin folder so I can distribute to other machines/OS's. Thanks for your help!